# Receiving multiline string from user input in a python telegram bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am using python-telegram-bot. This is my Python handler for the CommandHandler:

```
async def bulk_q(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    questions_user = ' '.join(context.args[:])
```

It is intended to allow the user to send questions in bulk, one question at a time, and I'm especially interested on catching the `\n` so that I can do a for-loop over each line of input.

However, if I log the content of `context.args`, there is no `\n` anywhere.

Would it be possible to extract each line of text I receive from the user independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just access the original text of the message via `update.(effective_)message.text`, see [here](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.text) and [here](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.update.html#telegram.Update.effective_message). You can then use the std-libraries [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) method.

As Imi already pointed out, [`CallbackContext.args`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.callbackcontext.html#telegram.ext.CallbackContext.args) is mainly intended for commands with arguments

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Answer (score -3):

**context.args** is a list that contains the command arguments, and it's already split by whitespace (spaces and newlines). If you want to extract each line of text, I suggest you first join the arguments and then split them by newline character **('\n')**. Here's an example of how you can modify your **bulk_q** function to achieve this:

```
async def bulk_q(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
# Join the arguments with a space, then split by newline character
questions_raw = ' '.join(context.args[:])
questions_list = questions_raw.split('\n')

# Process each question
for question in questions_list:
    # Your processing code here
    pass
```

Keep in mind that this assumes the user sends the questions using the newline character. If they're sending questions in separate messages, you'll need to handle those messages differently. If that's the case, you can store the questions in a list and process them as needed.

Comment: I already tried this. It's not working because there is no `\n`